# Get POST data in PHP

Tags: php, android, api, post, http-post

So I'm running this to retrieve my POST data:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If I go to print out the `$jsonString`, I get the results like so:

> Something=Value&OtherThing=Value&Etc=Yougetmydrift

Now in the past I've been able to do this:

```
$object = json_decode($jsonString);
$something = $object->Something;
echo $something; // would print 'Value'
```

But I'm currently experiencing this not working. I'm working with the Android SDK and `php://input` on the back end seems to be returning nothing. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I haven't worked with Android at all, but I am curious - how come you're not using $_POST to retrieve the POST-ed data? It doesn't work or is there some other reason to it?

Comment: Post data should be accessible from $_POST. Also the data you try to parse as JSON isn't formated as JSON.

Comment: Yea I don't know why I didn't try that first :/ Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
echo $_POST["Something"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to do `file_get_contents('php://input');`.  PHP automatically fills the variable `$_POST` with post data.

```
echo $_POST['Something']; // Value
```

Also, just FYI: `Something=Value&OtherThing=Value&Etc=Yougetmydrift` isn't JSON, it's a query string.  If you *really* wanted to parse it, you should use `parse_str($string, $result)`<sup>[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)</sup>.

Comment: Yea I knew it wasn't JSON. I guess that's because I'm not sending it out as JSON... Will have to see how to encode as JSON from android...

Comment: Good call tho. I'm using an API written by someone else trying to port over to another device. I think I need to encode the android code by JSON to make it work with that API. That or rewrite it all!

Comment: @ing0: You don't need to send it out as JSON, using `$_POST['Something']` works fine.

Comment: +1. No, I do need to send it out as JSON. The API is already written like that! All I've had to change is the way I'm encoding the POST data. But I understand that in most situations using $_POST would be the ideal solution.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that! At least I got it working. I'd change it if I had time but it works just the same. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the `file_get_contents('php://input');` style is usually used for PUT data. For POST PHP provides a built in super-global array called $_POST.

Answer (score -2):

use: `urldecode` / `urlencode`, not `json_decode`

Comment: urldecode just converts `%##` entities from a url string. It doesn't convert the url string to an array/object.

Comment: yes, you're right, what I've ment to post is this: parse_url ; http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: unfortunately parse_url won't work either. If you pass it a simple query string like in the question, you will get back `null`. Even if you pass it a full url, it doesn't parse the query to an array/object, but returns just a string that consists of the query portion.

Comment: Actually you need [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str), not [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: write it manually :D split it by =, assign the array keys as the array values, and return / convert it to an object :) problem solved